# Angular: Input recognize if the input got entered by tab

Tags: angular, onfocus

I want to call a function when the cursor jumps to an input, but only when this happens due to a tab key. That's why I can't use the (focus) event, because that also gets triggered by a click. Is there a way to trigger a function when the cursor jumps into the input by tab key?

Comment: Can you check ```ev.which == 13``` in (focus)

Comment: I don't know why, but I only get `0` as `ev.which`...

Comment: Might the reason for that be, that the [UIEvent.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which) is deprecated? Is there a newer method on how to get the key?

Comment: saw that, then I think you can listen to window.addEventListener('keydown') and input (focus) event and some how merge them by Rxjs oprators after  fromEvent($event);

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Component Dev Kit (CDK) from Angular Material you can use [FocusMonitor](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#focusmonitor) to recognize if the element was focused by keyboard, mouse, touch or via code.

Install npm packet:

```
npm install @angular/cdk --save
```

Import `A11yModule` to your module (for example app.module.ts).

Then add directive cdkMonitorElementFocus to your element. Now you want to  use the (cdkFocusChange) event instead of (focus).

.html:

```
<input cdkMonitorElementFocus (cdkFocusChange)="onFocusChange($event)" value="" />
```

.ts:

```
onFocusChange(origin: FocusOrigin): void {
  if (origin == null) {
    // element blured
  } else if (origin == 'keyboard') {
    // focused via keyboard
  } else if (origin == 'mouse' || origin == 'touch') {
    // focused via mouse or touch
  } else if (origin == 'program') {
    // focused via code
  }
}
```

If you want to monitor a whole subtree of many elements you can use the directive cdkMonitorSubtreeFocus on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to handle this scenario using (focus) event alone.

Let me suggest you an alternate way. This may not a 100% valid solution. But this works in my requirement.

Solution:

```
// Declare one boolean variable and assign it to false.

isClicked = false;

// Create a function to detect mouse down event

onMouseDown() {
  this.isClicked = true;
}

// Create a function to detect mouse up event

onMouseDown() {
  this.isClicked = false;
}

// Create a function to detect focus event

onFocus() {
  if (this.isDown) {
    console.log('click event')
  } else {
    console.log('tab event')
  }
}
```

And here is a sample input box in html with these events.

```
<input
    class="target"
    (mousedown)="down()"
    (mouseout)="out()"
    value=""
    (focus)="test($event)"
  />
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, but this also doesn't work, as the focus also get fired by other functions, it must really be determined that the focus is triggered with the tabulator key and a conclusion cannot be drawn by pressing the mouse key. But thank you anyway!